# Whats the point of building a server when you can download one like redhat?

Tags: node.js, express, server, redhat

I'm learning node.js and express.js right now in my programming class and I can't wrap my mind around why we are building a server when we can just download one. I found this website and i'm still not convinced especially for number 4 http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-reasons-server/

Answer (score 2):

Node, Express, and pretty much any sort of programming language / web framework can be used to build *anything*, not just servers.

Servers are really an abstract concept.

The link you provided is referring to servers as pieces of hardware. What is a server? It's nothing fancy -- just a computer that is running some programs. The computer you're using right now (most likely a laptop), can be used as a server. So can a desktop PC. So can anything else.

Now, what your class is likely teaching you is how to build a *web server*. A web server is NOT a physical thing. It's just a piece of software that runs on a computer.

Servers in the software world refer to pieces of software that run for a long time, and do something.

With Node and Express, for instance, you can write a piece of web server software that shows a webpage every time someone makes an HTTP request to that server.

So, to answer your question:

- Physical servers are just computers.
- Software servers are just pieces of software that run for a long time and do something when requested.
- RedHat is just an operating system (like Windows, and Mac). It is NOT a server at all -- just an OS.

Hopefully this clarifies things for you =)